# Does the main procedure in an assembly program need a stack frame?

Tags: assembly, x86

If the main procedure has local variables and alters the stack pointer, should you bother making a stack frame like you would in a normal procedure?

Comment: What ABI are you using?

Comment: @RaymondChen I don't even know what an ABI is

Comment: cant hurt right?

Comment: @William An ABI (application binar interface) is a specification for how data is laid out in memory, how functions are called, and everything else that is needed to have functions in machine code interact with the operating system and each other.  This document often specifies what the stack looks like on program start which is what you are interested in.

Comment: Notably, each operating system and architecture has a different ABI.  So without you being more specific, your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: By “making a stack frame” if you mean saving ebp and loading ebp from esp, then the answer is no, neither main nor any other procedure needs to do that, whether written in assembly or compiler generated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: it depends

Best practice answer: probably

Lazy answer: if it doesn't crash it's good enough. ( /sarcasm )

Detailed answer:

It really depends on what you're doing with your function. Stack frame link omission is an optimization some compilers do themselves, actually. (Which is where it may omit creation of the stack frame, to my knowledge.)

Really, stack frames, unless your code needs them, only exist for debugging purposes (to make walking the stack easier). And I'll let you in on a little secret: the computer couldn't give two segfaults what you do with the stack so long as when the function returns, the stack is in the state it was when the function was called. (Exempting some ABIs which expect the called function to clean up the stack.)

So, really, you don't need a stack frame. You don't even need a stack frame if you intend to actually return from your function, so long as the stack pointer is the same as it was when you entered.

If you're exiting via a return, then yes, you need to restore the stack pointer. If you're exiting via calling `exit` then it's pretty much fair game, so far as how you treat the stack goes. (As long as you make sure interrupt handlers don't clobber any program data.)

Though I do agree with the comments on your original question. It's help to know exactly which ABI you're targeting. Because while what I've said generally holds true, stuff gets weird with some ABIs, and without knowing which ABI you are targeting a definitive answer cannot be given.

Comment: *Lazy answer: if it doesn't crash it's good enough* That's often not true in assembly.  In this case, maybe you have an ABI that depends on a chain of EBP frame pointers for stack unwinding in the debugger, or for printing messages when `abort()` is called.  A simple `main()` would work fine because you didn't invoke anything that depended on unwinding the stack back through main.  But you'd break those debugging / info features.

Comment: And more generally that's a terrible approach to asm development; please don't suggest it even as a joke.  e.g. a function that uses EBX without saving/restoring it might not break some callers, but then changing something in that function's caller could lead to crashes when the problem is *not* in the code that changed, but rather in code you wrote a long time ago that violates the ABI and no longer gets away with it.  (But overall good answer.)

Comment: Or if you use stack space below ESP, you won't crash until a signal handler runs at the wrong moment, or you use GDB to `print some_func()` which gets GDB to call that function using the current stack.

Comment: It is a terrible answer. I presume someone working with assembly will be smart enough to recognize a bad idea when they see one.

Comment: Many SO questions about asm are from total beginners, e.g. people who are taking an asm class, or who read something and don't have the background knowledge to understand it yet.  (Otherwise they wouldn't have to ask.)

Comment: Mhm. I'll edit that part out if you'd like. I suppose light humor has no place on SO.

Comment: It does, as long as you make it obvious with a "(just kidding)" or something.  Sarcastic dry humour isn't a good fit for technical writing without any warning for people who don't get the joke.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the main procedure in an assembly program need a stack frame?

If you look at a complete system (everything from firmware all the way up to some JavaScript buried in a web page); software is a tall tower of crumbling unstable pieces (maybe like Jenga).

At the bottom of this tower is machine code - numbers, where the hardware (CPU) reacts in certain ways to different numbers. At this level there is no procedures and no stack; just instructions (e.g. `call`) that might or might not be used to implement procedures and instructions (e.g. `push`, `pop`) that might or might not be used to implement a stack.

The next layer up is assembly language - a text representation of the machine code. At this level there still might or might not be procedures and might or might not be a stack. For some cases (early startup code in firmware that's executed before memory controllers are configured) there might not even be any usable RAM.

The next layer up is a pile of conventions that are typically stolen from an implementation of a higher level language. This is procedures/functions, stack, calling conventions, etc. Of course this can be completely different for different languages and different implementations of the same language; and (at least in theory - e.g. a language designed for "continuation passing style" and nothing else) might still not include things like procedures and (at least in theory - e.g. maybe a functional programming language with a compiler designed to convert all code into lookup tables) might not include a stack, and if there is a stack it might actually be two (or more?) stacks (e.g. one stack for control flow and another stack for data, for security/control-flow integrity purposes).

The next layer up is a pile of conventions for debugging. This is where frame pointers came from (from a desire to add debugging to implementations of old C compilers). Of course for more modern systems debuggers have moved on to "less silly" approaches (shifting information debuggers need out of the machine code where it's a performance/optimization problem and into a special tables - e.g. the "Call Frame Information table" for DWARF).

Essentially; for assembly itself, there may be no procedures, no stack and no frame pointer; but if the assembly language programmer is trying to write code that complies with "environmental conventions" they probably will use procedures and might use frame pointers.

For an example, here's some "pseudo-assembly" for a simple calculator:

```
start:
    mov r7,doNextOperator        ;r7 = address "get number" code should jump to
    jmp getNumber

doNextOperator:
    mov r0,r1                    ;r0 = accumulator = result
    out diplay,r0                ;Display the current accumulator
    in r2, nextChar              ;r2 = next operator from user
    mov r7,[operatorTable+r2*4]  ;r7 = address "get number" code should jump to
    jmp getNumber

operatorTable:
    dd doAddition
    dd doSubtraction
    dd doMultiplication
    dd doDivision


;Do addition
;========================
;Input
; r0    Accumulator
; r1    Number to add
;
;Output
; r1    Result

doAddition:
   add r1,r0
   jmp doNextOperator

;Do subtraction
;========================
;Input
; r0    Accumulator
; r1    Number to add
;
;Output
; r1    Result

doAddition:
   sub r1,r0
   jmp doNextOperator


;Get a number from the user
;========================
;Input
; r7    Address to jump to when finished
;
;Output
; r1    Number entered by the user 

getNumber:
    mov r1,0
    in r2, nextChar
    sub r2,'0'
    jc .done
.next:
    mul r1,10
    add r1,r2
    in r2, nextChar
    sub r2,'0'
    jnc .next
.done:
    jmp r7
```